# FireBase update & remove child only once although multiple user executed simultaneously

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My multiplayer games require to remove a specific firebase child node and update their own player node once. Here is the problem, there are possibility, more than one user will update their own player node simultaneously if they press the button on the same time.

So my question is, how do I restrict only run the logic in doTransaction for the first user who press the button? For the rest of the user who press the button, there will run the other logic differently.

Here is the code:

```
start = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.start);
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updatePlayer();
        }

private void updatePlayer() {  
final Iterator<DataSnapshot> playerIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator(); 

mDatabase.child("Challenger").child("Pro").child(challengerKey).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                @Override
                                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {


                                    if (currentData.getValue().toString() != null) {

                                        foundChallenger = currentData.getValue().toString();

                                        // Remove from server
                                        mDatabase.child("Challenger").child(state.getPlayer().getRank()).child(challengerKey).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                                Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "removeValueOnComplete");
                                                Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "databaseError" + databaseError);                                                   
                                            }
                                        });

                                        // Add new data to player node
                                        ArrayList<String> newChallengerList;


                                        newChallengerList = new ArrayList<String>();
                                     newChallengerList.add(foundChallenger);

                                        Map<String, Object> challengerUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                                        challengerUpdates.put("challengerList", newChallengerList);

                                        mDatabase.child("Player").child(state.getUid()).updateChildren(challengerUpdates);


                                    } else {
                                        Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "no current data!");
                                        return Transaction.abort();
                                    }

                                    return Transaction.success(currentData);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "committed: " + committed);
                                    Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "databaseError: " + databaseError);
                                    Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "databaseError: " + dataSnapshot);

                                    if (!committed) {

                                    }

                                }
                            }, false);

                        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                            Log.d(GoogleServiceApi.TAG, "no challenger currently!");
                        }
 }
```